# Editing a movie from DVD in Sony Vegas?

Tags: video, file-formats, vegas-pro

I often have a movie (commercial, encrypted DVD) which I would like to import into Sony Vegas for further editing. The goal is to make my own private "Director's Cut", mixing the movie with some other movie snippets from different source ("Making Of" from different DVD).

My usual workflow: I decypt the DVD with DVD Decrypter. Then I got a couple of decrypted VOB files and a few other files. If I open the VOB files with Sony Vegas 8.0, this approach usually works fine, I can just open the VOB file and have the movie on the timeline and can edit it, then re-render to my liking.

However, there are two problems with this approach:

1.) Sometimes, even though I open the VOB files in the right order, the movie parts from some of the VOB files are truncated down to a few seconds in the timeline.

2.) With Vegas 11.0, this approach does not seem to work at all: I can't even see the decrypted VOB files when I do File --> Open and the navigate to the directory with the decrypted VOB files in it.

How can I alleviate this? Is there a better approach? I wonder if if I could go via some lossless AVI intermediate that's easier to import into Vegas? I searched the net, but one problem is that there is a lot of outdated tutorials out there for this specific problem. Would really appreciate some help/ideas.

Software and versions I'm using:
DVD Decrypter 3.5.4.0
Sony Vegas 8.0
Sony Vegas 11.0
Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr). If you rip the DVD using Handbrake, you will get a single file, which you can then import into Vegas.

Comment: Does Handbrake generate a lossless intermediate? (I do not want to just transcode the DVD to a lossy mp4 version and then again transcode a second time in vegas, introducing additional loss.)